# Map Disappers after changing the styles to increse it width and height

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I am trying to change the width and height of the map. I want to show the map on full width of the page. Map is visible on half of the page without any styles.  but when i try to implement styles to change height the map disappears from the page.

here is the full code of my html with the styles in the head tag and map div is at the bottom.

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <!-- Style Sheets includes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/customstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Script includes -->
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.14" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="data.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="initmap.js"></script>
    <style>
    html, body, #map {
        width: 25%;
        height: 25%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
        position: relative;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ApplicationController as appctrl">



    <div class="container">



<div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the function for Initialize map

```
//Initializes the map.
function initialize() {

    // Initial options. Centers on Sierra Leone.
    var mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: 8.4494988, lng: -11.7868289},
            zoom: 8
    };
    // Creates the map.
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);

}
```

Comment: What was the map size originally? What did you change it to?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue

Comment: I just implemented the div not the styles. i want to change the width of the map..

Comment: here is the minimal code

Comment: There is no code to create a map, how would you expect it to show?  You need to provide the contents of the (relevant) external files (like initmap.js).  This is a duplicate, you are using a percentage size of an element that doesn't have a size (the `<div>` with class="container").

Comment: let me  share it to..

Comment: you are not getting me.. when i try to implement styles to change the widht.. map disappers otherwise it is visiable on the page.. but the map is small . i want to increase its width. thats why i want to increase its width.

Comment: Code with lots of commented out bits definitely does not qualify for a **minimal**, complete, tested and readable example that desmontrates the issue. Also provide a JSFiddle or a snippet.

Comment: I remove the comments but i don't know how to use jsfiddle

Comment: I'm sure if you tried you'd find out. If you know how to copy, paste and click you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you change the size of the map div you need to resize the map  (resize event of google maps) for a correct  view of the content

In your case after  change dinamically the size of div  you can easily (re) invoke your  initialize function...
(better if you before set map to null)

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a basic map, a Street View image, driving directions, or a search into your website or blog from Google Maps.

When your viewers are signed in to Google, they can also see their home and work, saved places, and more in your map.

Get the code

**[Open Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps)**
Make sure the map or Street View image you'd like to embed shows up on the map.
In the top left corner, click the main menu ​.
Click Share or embed map.
At the top of the box that appears, choose the Embed map tab.
Choose the size you want, then copy the code and paste it into the source code of your website or blog.
Note: If you're using Maps in Lite mode, you won't be able to embed a map.